# How can I use my phone as a monitor?

Tags: usb, android

I would like to use my phone (LG K8) as a monitor for my raspberry pi where network connections are not available. How is it possible?

I shall also mention that I do have the official touchscreen but it is too large for my purposes and VNC did not work as neither of the devices will have access to any network where this will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Make the phone a hotspot. Connect the R-Pi to it. Use 'Fing' (get it from your favourite app store) on the phone to scan and detect the R-Pi IP address and use VNC to connect. That may work.

Comment: I have attempted to use this method but my phone is unable to find my RPi.

Comment: Can you make the R-Pi find and connect to the hotspot SSID?

Comment: It can do that but my phone becomes stuck attempting to connect.

Comment: Using the RealVNC app on the phone? VNC enabled on the R-Pi?

Answer (score 0):

Try VNC, remote screen over IP.

Comment: I have already attempted this but I could only get it to work over a network connection.

Comment: Yes thats the only way you can use a phone as a display.

Comment: Is there no screen mirroring app that will work?

Comment: What you are asking for is, "How can I turn a output into a input".